# Converting an Object into a string using JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, object

I am using an API that delivers the following data / value object:

```
Object {left: "704.4026794075746px", top: "171.54992155622406px"}
```

I need to be able to take the left and top coordinates for use with jquery's css method.

Would I convert this object into a string and then parse the string? How would I go about using the data within the object within jquery's css or animate methods?

Sorry for no context, but I am unsure of where to start here.

Comment: these are some high-precision coordinates! I want to see the monitor that benefits from them!

Comment: @StenPetrov LOL that seems very very precise.

Comment: Haha they are dynamically created for ULTIMATE precision!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass that object into jQuery's `.css` function.

```
$('selector').css(cssObject);
```

Comment: No problem @JCHASE11 I am happy to help! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If the object is in a variable named `someObject`, you access the properties as:

```
someObject.left
```

and

```
someObject.top
```

You can us it in a call to `css()`:

```
$('selector').css("left", someObject.left);
```

Or you could pass the whole object as Neal showed in his answer.